# what domain should we take

Tags: calculus, functions

i am practicing to draw the graphs of some rational power functions to identify vertical tangents and cusp for instance

$$f(x)=(2-x)^{\frac{1}{5}}$$

But one of my friends said that the domain of $f(x)^x$ if  $x$ is a rational number is all $x$ for which $f(x) \gt 0$.

And as he said Yes, some graphing calculators is giving according to the domain what my friend said, but some giving the domain as $\mathbb{R}$. so which domain we should consider?

Comment: Are you trying to draw the graph of the equation $y=(2-x)^{1/5}$ or the equation $y=(2-x)^{x/5}$?  (If only the former, why are you concerned about the latter?)

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If we are looking at $f(x)^x$, we can rewrite this as $g(x) = (2-x)^{\frac{x}{5}}$. In that case, we have the condition that if $2-x=0 \Rightarrow x\neq 0$ which is obviously true. The last condition is $2-x\geq 0$, so $x\leq 2$. So the domain is $D = \lbrace x\in \mathbb R; x\leq 2 \rbrace$.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the $a=0$ case, $x^a$ is defined when $x\ge0$ for $a>0$, and when $x>0$ for $a<0$, as it stems from $x^a=e^{a \ln x}$, resorting to the limit (in $x$) in the first case. Plus, it is defined everywhere when $a$ is a positive integer, and everywhere except $0$ when $a$ is negative.

So far, your domain is $x\le 2$.

Then, one sometimes interprets $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$, with $n$ a positive integer (here $n=5$), as the [$n$-th root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root) $\sqrt[n]{x}$. When $n$ is odd, this is defined for every $x$. So your domain would be $\mathbb{R}$.